# how to place title at end of a navigation bar in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I am new to css and react and I found a code of a navigation bar in reactjs online and I am trying to style it on my own and currently, it looks like this.

[image]

And here is what I am trying to make it look like

[image]

So the only thing that I am trying to do is to get the "sample" title to the left.

I thought it was a issue of flex direction so I changed `justify-content:center` to  `justify-content:flex-end` but that did not work.

Here is my react code

```
return (
        <>
            <Nav scrollNav={scrollNav}>
                <NavbarContainer>
                    <NavLogo to='/' onClick={toggleHome}>sample</NavLogo>
                    <MobileIcon onClick={toggle}>
                        <FaBars />
                    </MobileIcon>
                    <NavMenu>
                        <NavItem>
                            <NavLinks
                            to='about'
                            smooth={true}
                            duration={500}
                            spy={true}
                            exact='true'
                            offset={-80}>About</NavLinks>
                        </NavItem>
                        <NavItem>
                            <NavLinks to='experience' 
                            smooth={true}
                            duration={500}
                            spy={true}
                            exact='true'
                            offset={-80}>API for business</NavLinks>
                        </NavItem>
                        <NavItem>
                            <NavLinks to='blog'
                            smooth={true}
                            duration={500}
                            spy={true}
                            exact='true'
                            offset={-80}>Blog</NavLinks>
                        </NavItem>
                    </NavMenu>
                   

                </NavbarContainer>
            </Nav>
        </>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

And here is the styling part of it

```
export const Nav = styled.nav`
  background: #FFF;
  margin-top: -80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: left;
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;

  @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    transition: 0.8s all ease;
  }
`;

export const NavbarContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 24px;
  max-width: 1100px;
`;

export const NavLogo = styled(LinkR)`
  color: #000;
  justify-self: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
`;

export const MobileIcon = styled.div`
  display: none;

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(-100%, 60%);
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
  }
`;

export const NavMenu = styled.ul`
  display: flex;
  align-items: right;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 2px;

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    display: none;
  }
`;

export const NavItem = styled.li`
  height: 80px;
`;

export const NavBtn = styled.nav`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    display: none;
  }
`;

export const NavLinks = styled(LinkS)`
  color: #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;

  &.active {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #01BF71;
  }
`;

export const NavBtnLink = styled(LinkR)`
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 10px 22px;
  color: #010606;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;

  &:hover {
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background: #fff;
    color: #010606;
  }
`;
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Is the screenshot with `justify-content: center;` or `justify-content: flex-end;` ? Remove `max-width: 1100px;` in `NavbarContainer` and tell me if it fixed it.

Comment: @SamiElk yes it worked! thank you so much. :)

Comment: Ok, I'll add the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `NavbarContainer` you have set the `max-width` property to 1100px.

The NavbarContainer won't expend past 1100px so it won't fill the whole header.

That's why the logo isn't on the far left you center your NavbarContainer with `justify-content:center` or set it `flex-end`.